# How do I get all the LI UL elements ID value and place them in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have to embed some tracking code on my site. So I have a list of LI elements with an ID value that I want to place inside an array of the snippet. They should be numeric like, 123, 456, etc inside an object. I want to do it in pure JavaScript.

This is my code I have tried. My HTML:

```
<ul id="itemGrid">  
    <li class="item" id="1080">  product code </li>
    <li class="item" id="1487">  product code </li>    
    <li class="item" id="1488">  product code </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

This is the JavaScript code

```
// Get all LI items and get the ID of them in the object viewList
var catId = document.getElementById('itemGrid').getElementsByTagName('li');

window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
    window.criteo_q.push(
        // SHOULD BE LIKE THIS
        // { event: "viewList", item: ["First item id", "Second item id", "Third item id"] }
        // My actual code
        { event: "viewList", item: [ catId[].id ] }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all the matching elements passed as selector.

The selector `'#itemGrid li[id]'` will select all the `<li>` elements inside `#itemGrid` element having `id` attribute on it.

The `querySelectorAll` returns a collection of HTML elements. Iterate over this collection to get the individual element id.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#itemGrid li[id]');

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  arr.push(+lis[i].id);
}

console.log(arr);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<ul id="itemGrid">
  <li class="item" id="1080">1080</li>
  <li class="item" id="1487">1487</li>
  <li class="item" id="1488">1488</li>
</ul>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var lis = document.getElementById('itemGrid').getElementsByTagName('li');
var idArray = [];
for ( var counter = 0; counter < lis.length; counter++)
{
   idArray.push( lis[ counter ].id );
}
console.log( idArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `HTMLCollection` to an Array by passing it through `slice`, and you can then `map` that array:

```
catId = Array.prototype.slice.call(catId).map(function(li) { return li.id; });
```

---

```js
var catId = document.getElementById('itemGrid').getElementsByTagName('li');
catId = Array.prototype.slice.call(catId).map(function(li) { return li.id; });

document.write(catId);
```

```html
<ul id="itemGrid">  
    <li class="item" id="1080">  product code </li>
    <li class="item" id="1487">  product code </li>    
    <li class="item" id="1488">  product code </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this require the prototype library? If so downvote.

Comment: No, this is native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lis = document.getElementById('itemGrid').getElementsByTagName('li');
var arr = [];

// You need to iterate the list lis
[].forEach.call( lis, function(el){
     arr.push( el.id );
});

// Making the object you want
var criteo_q = { event: "viewList", item: arr };
console.log(criteo_q);
```

To iterate the `list` of DOM elements, you can also use